# Voyager Laravel не работают картинки

Tags: php, laravel, изображения

Всем привет! Пробую админ-панель Voyager для Laravel. Заметил что все картинки не выводятся, а на их месте значок ошибки. Поискал в конфигурационном файле Voyager информацию по filesystem. Он использует public. Отредактировал его для того что бы был корректный путь к картинке, но при этом всё равно ошибка осталась

filesystems.php

```html
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ссылку добавили, как это указано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk)?

Comment: @daniel-protopopov The [C:\wamp64\www\jolyPanel\public\storage] link already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем привет ещё раз! Всё решил тем, что в APP_ENV к http://localhost я добавил /название_папки_проекта